# Utilizar For em JavaScript em uma concatenação HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Olá,

eu estou em um arquivo JavaScript e exibindo uma tabela HTML por ele com uma concatenação HTML, só que preciso fazer um **for** em uma das colunas da tabela para exibir as opção de um select, mas sem sucesso.

Modo que não está funcionando, acredito que seja por alguma coisa da concatenação do HTML (está entre * o for):

```
function listAjustes(){
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : 'diversos/show',
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.diversos.length; i++){
                html += '<tr id="'+data.diversos[i].id+'">'+
                        '<th class="tabela_ajuste" scope="row">'+data.diversos[i].agencia+'</th>'+
                        '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].mes+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].ano+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].data_lancamento+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].data_entrada+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].conta_razao+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].centro_lucro+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].nome_usuario+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].chave_lancamento+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].texto+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].montante+'</td>'+
                                                '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].conta_contabil+'</td>'+
                                                '<td ><select id="codigo" class="form-control" name="codigo" required="">'+
                                                    '<option value="">(Select)</option>'
                                              **for(j=0; j<data.codigos.length; j++){
                                                    '<option value="'+data.codigos[j].nome+'">'+data.codigos[j].nome+'</option>'
                                                }**

                                                '</td>'+
                        '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm editRecord" data-id="'+data[i].id+'" data-nome="'+data[i].nome+'" data-valor="'+data[i].valor+'" data-ano="'+data[i].ano+'">Editar</a>'+' '+
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm deleteRecord" data-id="'+data[i].id+'">Excluir</a>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
            }
            $('#listajustes').html(html);                   
        }
    });
    }
```

Pois se eu faço com um só elemento da certo.

```
'<td ><select id="codigo" class="form-control" name="codigo" required="">'+
 '<option value="">(Select)</option>'+
 '<option value="'+data.codigos[0].nome+'">'+data.codigos[0].nome+'</option>'+
'</td>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta isso

```
function listAjustes(){
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : 'diversos/show',
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.diversos.length; i++){
                html += '<tr id="'+data.diversos[i].id+'">'+
                        '<th class="tabela_ajuste" scope="row">'+data.diversos[i].agencia+'</th> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].mes+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].ano+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].data_lancamento+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].data_entrada+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].conta_razao+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].centro_lucro+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].nome_usuario+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].chave_lancamento+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].texto+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].montante+'</td> \
                        <td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].conta_contabil+'</td> \
                        <td ><select id="codigo" class="form-control" name="codigo" required=""> \
                        <option value="">(Select)</option>';

                        for(j=0; j<data.codigos.length; j++){
                            html += '<option value="'+data.codigos[j].nome+'">'+data.codigos[j].nome+'</option>'
                        }

                        $html += '</td> \
                        <td style="text-align:right;"> \
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm editRecord" data-id="'+data[i].id+'" data-nome="'+data[i].nome+'" data-valor="'+data[i].valor+'" data-ano="'+data[i].ano+'">Editar</a> \
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm deleteRecord" data-id="'+data[i].id+'">Excluir</a>\
                        </td> \
                        </tr>';
            }
            $('#listajustes').html(html);                   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Além de ter faltado fechar o `<select>`, você poderia fazer o `for` das options **uma única vez** (já que provém a mesma array `data.codigos` para todos os selects) em vez de realizar o mesmo `for` várias vezes dentro do `for` principal:

```
var opts = '';
for(j=0; j<data.codigos.length; j++){
   opts += '<option value="'+data.codigos[j].nome+'">'+data.codigos[j].nome+'</option>';
}
```

Depois basta concatenar a variável `opts` no lugar onde você estava tentando fazer o `for`:

```
...
'<option value="">(Select)</option>'+
opts+
...
```

**Veja:**

```js
data = {
   diversos: [
      { id: 1, agencia: "ag1", mes: "mes1", ano: "ano1" },
      { id: 2, agencia: "ag2", mes: "mes2", ano: "ano2" }
   ],
   
   codigos: [
      { nome: "nome1" },
      { nome: "nome2" },
      { nome: "nome3" }
   ]
}

function listAjustes(){

   var opts = '';
   for(j=0; j<data.codigos.length; j++){
      opts += '<option value="'+data.codigos[j].nome+'">'+data.codigos[j].nome+'</option>';
   }

   var html = '';
   var i;
   for(i=0; i<data.diversos.length; i++){
       html += '<tr id="'+data.diversos[i].id+'">'+
               '<th class="tabela_ajuste" scope="row">'+data.diversos[i].agencia+'</th>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].mes+'</td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste">'+data.diversos[i].ano+'</td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td class="tabela_ajuste"></td>'+
               '<td ><select id="codigo" class="form-control" name="codigo" required="">'+
                   '<option value="">(Select)</option>'+
                   opts+
               '</select></td>'+
               '<td style="text-align:right;">botões'+
               '</td>'+
               '</tr>';
   }
   $('#listajustes').html(html);                
}
listAjustes();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="listajustes" border=1></table>
```